# Programmatically creating Excel file in C++

Tags: c++, excel, sdk

I have seen programs exporting to Excel in two different ways.

1. Opening Excel and entering data cell by cell (while it is running it looks like a macro at work)
2. Creating an Excel file on disk and writing the data to the file (like the Export feature in MS Access)

Number 1 is terribly slow and to me it is just plain aweful.

Number 2 is what I need to do. I'm guessing I need some sort of SDK so that I can create Excel files in C++.

1. Do I need different SDKs for .xls and .xlsx?
2. Where do I obtain these? (I've tried Googling it but the SDKs I've found looks like they do other things than providing an interface to create Excel files).
3. When it comes to the runtime, is MS Office a requirement on the PC that needs to create Excel files or do you get a redistributable DLL that you can deploy with your executable?

Comment: Does it have to be an Excel file? If all you're doing is exporting data, you can save [CSV files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) instead which is way, way easier to generate and Excel (or any non-dumb spreadsheet program) will have no problem opening it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can easily do that by means of the XML Excel format. Check the wikipedia about that:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#XML_Spreadsheet

This format was introduced in Excel 2002, and it is an easy way to generate a XLS file.

Comment: A very long time ago, I did this using just plain HTML, and renaming the file to xls, and Excel was happy with that too...

Comment: Another way to avoid using privative and extrange formats is creating a CSV file, the excel converts them correctly to xls.

Comment: I was just trying this. Not heard of it before. If I try to open the XLS file it says it is an untrusted source. I can click to still open it and it is viewable. But can we stop that warning?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try working with `XLS`/`XLSX` files over `ODBC` or `ADO` drivers just like databases with a limited usage. You can use some templates if you need formatting or create the files from stratch. Of course you are limited by playing with the field values that way. For styling etc. you will need to use an `Excel` API like `Microsoft`'s.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this via [Wt library's WTemplate](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WTemplate.html)

In short, I created the excel document I wanted in open office, and `save-as` `excel 2003 (.xml)` format.

I then loaded that in google-chrome to make it look pretty and copied it to the clipboard.

Now I'm painstakingly breaking it out into templates so that Wt can render a new file each time.